# Pattern to extract text between parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

How to extract string from `"("` and `")"` using pattern matching or anything. For example if the text is

> "Hello (Java)"

Then how to get only `"Java"`?

Comment: Propably starting with `indexOf`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you want to happen with nested brackets, e.g. "Hello (Foo and (Bar))"? What about situations with multiple brackets values, such as "Hello (Foo) and (Bar)"?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try this:

```
String x = "Hello (Java)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(x);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

or

```
String str = "Hello (Java)";
String answer = str.substring(str.indexOf("(")+1, str.indexOf(")"));
```

Comment: What if my input String has the same schema, but I want to extract both parts of it. ```str1="Hello "``` and ```str2="Java"```. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 43):

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher("Hello This is (Java) Not (.NET)");

while (regexMatcher.find()) {//Finds Matching Pattern in String
   matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));//Fetching Group from String
}

for(String str:matchList) {
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Java
.NET
```

---

What does `\\((.+?)\\)` mean?

This regular Expression pattern will start from `\\(` which will match `(` as it is reserved in regExp so we need escape this character,same thing for `\\)` and `(.*?)` will match any character zero or more time anything moreover in `()` considered as Group which we are finding.

Comment: how to get strings in the Expression ["1","5","7"]. The result should be "1", "5" and "7". Should we use like: `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");`

Comment: @user1182217 You can use `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\".*?\")");` and use matcher to fetch grop 1.

Comment: Why is the index 1 ?

Comment: @Divesh Good question. Actually, index 0 represents the whole pattern and to capture group index starts from 1. You can refer to official documentation for more details. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 23):

there is something even simpler than using regex:

```
String result = StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "(", ")");
```

In your example, `result` would be returned as "Java". I would recommend the StringUtils library for various kinds of (relatively simple) string manipulation; it handles things like null inputs automatically, which can be convenient.

Documentation for substringBetween():
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

There are two other versions of this function, depending on whether the opening and closing delimiters are the same, and whether the delimiter(s) occur(s) in the target string multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You should actually be using

```java
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(([^()]*)\\)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher("Hello This is (Java) Not (.NET)");

while (regexMatcher.find()) {
   matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
}

for(String str:matchList) {
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

The **`\(([^()]*)\)`** regex matches:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)`  - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

The `[^()]` is a negated character class that makes it impossible to match another `(` after initial `(` is matched with `\(`, thus, it ensures the *innermost* matches between two pairs of parentheses.

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/pQkxvj) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o5Qyuq/2).