# JAVA - How to get String in ${}

Tags: java

For example :

```
String str = "bla bla ${foo} ${foo1}";
```

How to get words "foo" and "foo1" ?

maybe my string is :

```
String str1 = "${foo2} bla bla ${foo3} bla bla";
```

How to get words "foo2" and "foo3" ?

Comment: One solution is using a regex.

Comment: What code have you written? What does it do? Help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'd myself search google for "java extract text between parenthesis". This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256478/pattern-to-extract-text-between-parenthesis) appears as first result.

Comment: [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) + [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) will help.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found some solution. using Pattern + Matcher.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the regex `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes. For example:

```
String str = "bla bla ${foo} ${foo1}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([\\w]+)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
/* Result:
foo
foo1
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\${(.*?)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find())
{
    //m.group(1) is your string. do what you want
}
```

this should work