# Java regex issue to get data in the brackets

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the data from String "Max(percentage(%))" or "Max(percentage)", what i need to get is "percentage(%)" or "percentage" in the brackets. I want to use one regex achieve the goal. Can someone help me? Below is my code:

```
String str = "Max(percentage)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()(.+?)(?=\\))");

String str = "Max(percentage(%))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()(.+?)(?<=\\))");
```

Comment: where's the `Matcher` part that actually tries matching it against a certain string?

Comment: See Existing Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256478/pattern-to-extract-text-between-parenthesis

Comment: `(?i)max\((?<val>.+)\)`

Comment: Does your regex work? What is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you might try the following regex?

```
 [^\(]*\(([0-9]+)[)%]?\)
```

Answer (score -1):

Following regex can handle one level of nested parenthesis (to match any number of level a recursive regex should be used but it's not supported by java).

Regex

```
(?<=Max\()[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*(?=\))
```

Java code

```
String str = "Max(percentage(%))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Max\\()[^()]*(?:\\([^()]*\\)[^()]*)*(?=\\))");
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say use "or" operator | to check whether you have a percentage or a percentage plus (%):

```
    String str1 = "Max(32)";
    String str2 = "Max(32(%))";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Max\\((.+|.+\\(%\\))\\)");

    Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(str1);
    if (matcher1.find()) {
        System.out.println("percentage = " + matcher1.group(1));
    }

    Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(str2);
    if (matcher2.find()) {
        System.out.println("percentage(%) = " + matcher2.group(1));
    }
```