# How can I get the part of the string which is inside the characters like brackets i.e. "(" " )"?

Tags: java, string

Below are three strings. Each string has some characters inside the brackets. I want to save those characters which are inside the brackets in some other variables. Can somebody suggest the possible ways to do this?

```
String name_and_code1 = "MountainBlues(MB)"; 
String name_and_code2 = "Rock(RoRo)Roll";
String name_and_code3 = "(TFT)TitForTat";
```

Comment: find the indices and use substring

Comment: use `indexOf`, `substring` or regular expressions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pattern to extract text between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256478/pattern-to-extract-text-between-parenthesis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of indexOf(). First, find the indices of '(' and ')' and then use substring(). Something like:

```
int start = myString.indexOf('(');
int end = myString.indexOf(')');
String result = myString.substring(start+1, end); 
//start+1 because we don't want the '('
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression:

```
String a = "MountainBlues(MB)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\((.+)\\)").matcher(a);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

prints `MB`

Comment: For optimization the `Pattern` could be saved inside a `static` variable

Comment: Correct, but not appropriate at the level at OP's experience.

Answer (score 1):

```
String insideBrackets(String input){
    String result = "";
    boolean bracket = false;
    for(int i = 0: i < input.length(); i++){
        if(!bracket && input.charAt(i) == '('){
            bracket = true;
        }
        if(bracket && input.charAt(i) == ')'){
            bracket = false;
        }
        if(bracket){
            result += input.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

i think this should work. if it doesnt tell me right away

Comment: Maybe use a `StringBuilder` as string concatenation in loops will produce a lot of garbage intermediate objects

Comment: maybe. but this smells like homework and i dont think they even touched stringbuilder yet. idk

Comment: Well if you already provide their homework, you should do it the correct way in the first place, but this way they learn probably nothing and just copy paste it. *shrug*

Comment: well that sure as hell is =true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(\\(.*\\)).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("mytext(with)parentheses");

if(m.matches()) {
    String inner = m.group(1); // now inner contains "(with)" (without quotes)
    //...
}
```