# Parse a line from a text file and access the value inside of the parentheses

Tags: java, parsing, colors, text-files, background-color

So i'm parsing a line from text file and getting a string like:

```
color(black)
```

or

```
color(RGB(142,0,0))
```

So I wrote a code:

```
private Sprite makeSpriteToBackGround(String line) {
        if (line.contains("color")) {
            ColorsParser colorsParser = new ColorsParser();
            Color color = colorsParser.colorFromString(line.substring(line.indexOf("RGB")));
            return new Sprite() {
                @Override
                public void drawOn(DrawSurface d) {
                    d.setColor(color);
                    d.fillRectangle(0, 0, 800, 600);
                }

                @Override
                public void timePassed() {
                }
            };
}
```

So my goal is to check whether the line contains "RGB" or not.
If it does - it will be parsed through my colorFromString parser function, and if not, it will just will be deployed as the color.

How  would you suggest me to parse the

```
color(black)
```

part?

because the RGB part works perfectlly.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check for the presence of `RGB` first, and then fallback to looking for known values in a lookup table.

```
Map<String, Color> colors = new HashMap<String, Color>() {{
    put("black", Color.BLACK);
    put("red", Color.RED);
    put("green", Color.GREEN);
    put("blue", Color.BLUE);
}};

Color color = null;
int rgbIndex = line.indexOf("RGB");
if (rgbIndex > -1) {
    color = colorsParser.colorFromString(line.substring(rgbIndex));
} else {
    // There are better ways to extract text between brackets, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256478/pattern-to-extract-text-between-parenthesis/24256532
    String colorName = line.substring(line.indexOf("(") + 1, line.indexOf(")"));
    color = colors.get(colorName);
}

// TODO: Make sure you check if `color` is null here.
```

Comment: but there are a lot of colors, I think it wouldn't be efficient to create a map of ALL the colors .. I mean are u suggesting to create a map that contains X colors ? because I need to cover all colors. think about it , you may receive color(black.darker) or something..

Comment: @DimaCiun That’s true. Then you probably want to find a library thst contains the mappings that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestColor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fullColorStr = "color(yellow)";
        
        //Precondition
        if (fullColorStr == null || fullColorStr.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Color cannot be empty");
        }
        
        String colorStr = fullColorStr.substring(fullColorStr.indexOf("(")+1,fullColorStr.indexOf(")"));
        Color color = getColorFromString(colorStr);
        System.out.print(color);
    }

    private static Color getColorFromString(String colorStr) {
        //Precondition
        if (colorStr == null || colorStr.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        Color color = null;
        String lowerColorStr = colorStr.toLowerCase();
        try {
            Field colorField = Color.class.getField(lowerColorStr);
            //Paranoid check start
            Class<?> type = colorField.getType();
            if (type != Color.class) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Shoudln't have encountered this : " + colorStr);
            } //End 
            color = (Color) colorField.get(Color.class);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid color : " + colorStr);
        }
        return color;
    }

}
```

Comment: you wrote a code that gets "yellow", but my function receives a string of "color(yellow)"

Comment: Getting the text was already mentioned in the previous answer moreover your code suggested you knew how to extract stuff from a String. I wanted to provide you a way without hardcoding the colors.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the line of code to extract "yellow" from "color(yellow)"

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why none of the other commenters has already mentioned it, but there is an established way to solve this class of problems: **Regular Expressions**

You described two patterns:

- the named pattern: `color\((\w+)\)` ([see live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VJ2FPQ/1))
- the RGB pattern: `color\(RGB\((\d+)\,(\d+)\,(\d+)\)\)` ([see live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EshMYh/1))

Many deveolpers are afraid of Regular Expressions, but they are extremely helpful here. All you have to do in your code, is to pick the values from the matches:

```java
package color;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ColorParser {

    private final Pattern namedPattern = Pattern.compile("color\\((\\w+)\\)");
    private final Pattern rgbPattern = Pattern.compile("color\\(RGB\\((\\d+)\\,(\\d+)\\,(\\d+)\\)\\)");

    public Color parse(String line) {
        Color result = parseRGB(line);
        if (result == null) {
            result = parseNamed(line);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Color parseRGB(String line) {
        final Matcher matcher = rgbPattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            final int red = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
            final int green = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            final int blue = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
            return new Color(red, green, blue);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Color parseNamed(String line) {
        final Matcher matcher = namedPattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            final String name = matcher.group(1);
            try {
                // java.awt.Color is not an enum, so let's use Reflection
                return (Color) Color.class.getField(name.toUpperCase()).get(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is a JUnit test to verify it:

```java
package color;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.awt.Color;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ColorParserTest {

    final ColorParser sut = new ColorParser();

    @Test
    public void testParse_Named() {
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK, sut.parse("color(black)"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testParse_NamedInText() {
        assertEquals(Color.RED, sut.parse("foo color(Red) bar"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testParse_RGB() {
        assertEquals(Color.ORANGE, sut.parse("color(RGB(255,200,0))"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testParse_Unkown() {
        assertEquals(null, sut.parse("color(foo)"));
    }
}
```

I used the AWT Color class here. Depending on your use case you might need a mapping table to resolve other named colors, like [HTML colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names) or [X11 colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names).

Comment: I think you missed that the first answer had the link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256478/pattern-to-extract-text-between-parenthesis/24256532 which has the Regular expression option.